# Python: 'Vec2D' object does not support item assignment

Tags: python, rounding, turtle-graphics

Kinda of a follow-up from my last question but diverse enough that it compelled me to start a new thread. I need to round the coordinates of a point made by turtle from the Python turtle module, and any way which I try to do it gives me `TypeError: 'Vec2D' object does not support item assignment`.

I have `usedpositions: [[(-100.00,-0.00), 1], [(0.00,0.00), 2], [(100.00,0.00), 1]]`, where the zeroth item of every sublist is coords, and, long story short, I need to round it.

The first method I tried was

```
for upsublist in usedpositions:
    upsublist[0][0] = round(upsublist[0][0], 2)
    upsublist[0][1] = round(upsublist[0][1], 2)
```

This returned the aforementioned error, and so did

```
for upsublist in usedpositions:
    zeroth = round(upsublist[0][0], 2)
    first = round(upsublist[0][1], 2)
    upsublist[0][0] = zeroth
    upsublist[0][1] = first
```

So, I am just looking for a clean way to round the x- and y-coordinates to two decimal places. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Vec2D` is immutable; you can replace a `Vec2D` instance with a new vector containing rounded coordinates, but you cannot modify the original.

```
upsublist[0] = turtle.Vec2D(round(upsublist[0][0], 2), round(upsublist[0][1], 2))
```

Comment: Realize this is a while later, but your original answer was very informative. I tried to use this same technique later elsewhere with the somewhat redundant `search = [turtle.pos] (new line) search = [turtle.Vec2D(round(search[0], 2), round(search[1], 2))]` but ended up with `TypeError: type function doesn't define __round__ method`. Thanks for all your help.